# Which information googles admob needs to serve ads

Tags: android, admob

I would like to know which data googles admob sdk sends to admob for serving ads, especially for Android.
Candidates are gps data, android id,...
For example inmobi offers an api from which you can see what data you can serve inmobi for serving ads.

As far as i know google only provides an sdk which you can integrate in your app, but is there an api too?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the AdView to start sending ads you can provide an AdRequest into which you can supply whatever info you would like to provide.